# Azure Data Factory - Can we use local variables inside derived column in the data flow?

Tags: azure, variables, azure-data-factory

Experts,

I have a simple requirement where I need to store the value of a variable inside a column in my destination SQL Table (Sink).

Here's what I am doing:

1. Created a new pipeline and created a variable "createDate" with value "@utcNow"
2. I created a "data flow" task, where I configured my source (a simple CSV file) and added a "Derived Column" task because I want to store the date when the data was loaded in to my destination table
3. In my "Derived Column" task I added a new column "der_createDate", BUT, i don't know how can I assign the value of the "createDate" variable to this derived column, I tried several expressions like - @variables('createDate'), but, the expression validation fails.

How can I use the value of a variable created in the pipeline in any of "Data Flows"? Is it even possible? I have seen several use cases of variables in iterables or even in the "Copy Data" task, but, I am using Data Flows and would want to refer to those local variables i created in my pipeline. Let me know what you'd suggest.

Comment: Do you have to use variable `createDate` to store the @utcnow value?  You can generate the timestamp by [expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWmKd.png) in data flow.

Comment: Hi @PythonRookie, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. We can declare a variable `createDate` in the pipeline.
   [image]

2.Inside the dataflow we can declare a parameter `parameter1` and temporarily assign double quotes.
[image]

3. Then in the pipeline, select `Pipeline expression`, add dynamic value `@variables('createDate')`. So we can assign value of `createDate` to `parameter1`.
   [image]
4. In `DerivedColumn1` activity, we can generate a new column with the value of `parameter1`. There may be problems with the data preview, but the debugging result is correct. Because this column will assigned at runtime.
   [image]
5. The debugging result is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph, similar to this I have some other columns as well that I need to capture - like pipeline run id, name of the user and filenames being processed

Comment: So we can use parameter(createDate) in dataflow. I will show you one example when I back to desktop.

Comment: Hi @PythonRookie, I've updated my answer. Please correct me if I understand you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not supported in dataflow. You have to pass the value of this variable as a parameter(createDate) into dataflow and reference it as $createDate