# Using pipeline variables inside derived column in azure dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I have a variable in my pipeline that I would like to reference in my dataflow. I tried the steps listed here but my final result is an empty column.

[Azure Data Factory - Can we use local variables inside derived column in the data flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038559/azure-data-factory-can-we-use-local-variables-inside-derived-column-in-the-dat)

I've also tried to reference the variable in my parameter (by doing @variables('pipelinevariable') but am getting the error shown in the image

[referencing variables in parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vele.png)

Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the pipeline variable inside the dataflow. Dataflow expression doesn't recognize pipeline expressions and that's why it is giving the above error.

If you use any pipeline parameter in the derived column or any transformation, when you hit the data preview, the dataflow asks us to give the value for the parameter in the dataflow.

If you give value here, it will take this in the data preview.

[image]

I have given this parameter to `paramcol` column in the derived column and you can see the same value in the data preview.

[image]

To pass the pipeline variable to dataflow, you need to give it in the dataflow activity.

[image]

Click on pipeline expression and give `@variables('variable_name')`.

[image]

Dataflow takes this value from pipeline expression only during the debug of the pipeline. I have added a sink file in the dataflow and you can see the result in the sink file after the pipeline run.

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of this! thank you :) this is perfect